# NFSv4 server startup taking more time

Tags: nfs, nfsv4

I am trying to start nfsd daemon only for version 4. It takes more than 2.30 mins to come up.

```
# time /usr/sbin/rpc.nfsd -d -N 2 -N 3 -V 4.1 8
rpc.nfsd: knfsd is currently down
rpc.nfsd: Writing version string to kernel: -2 -3 +4 +4.1
rpc.nfsd: Created AF_INET TCP socket.

<<< hangs here for more than 2 mins >>>

rpc.nfsd: Created AF_INET6 TCP socket.

real    2m36.016s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.003s
```

When I run it with strace I could see it is waiting on socket write call().

```
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) = 4
write(2, "rpc.nfsd: ", 10rpc.nfsd: )              = 10
write(2, "Created AF_INET TCP socket.", 27Created AF_INET TCP socket.) = 27
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
setsockopt(4, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, [1], 4) = 0
bind(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(2049), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
listen(4, 64)                           = 0
write(3, "4\n", 2


<<< waiting here for more than 2 mins >>>


)                      = 2
close(3)                                = 0
close(4)                                = 0
```

Can someone help to find the root cause and fix it?

Update:
The issue is resolved when I enable and start rpcbind service before rpc.nfsd.
Why rpcbind service is required for NFSv4?

Comment: So what is `/proc/$PID/fd/3`?

Comment: It is the file descriptor of /proc/fs/nfsd/portlist.
`openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/fs/nfsd/portlist", O_WRONLY) = 3`

Comment: Sounds to me like something that is not allowed to happen. I guess it makes sense to contact the developers.

Comment: I missed to mention that I am not starting rpcbind service as it is not required for NFSv4.